# API JSON data import Google Sheets (JS)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please help me figure it out.
When unloading data, the entire array is written into one cell, how to split the data into cells and columns?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SYbU.png)

```
function pullJSON() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var options = {
    method: "GET",
   "headers" : {
      "Client-Id": "XXX",
      "Api-Key": "XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
   body: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
   // 'payload' : JSON.stringify({
   //  attribute_type: "REQUIRED",
   //  category_id: 17031211,
   // })
   }
  }

var url="https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v1/categories/tree"; // Paste your JSON URL here
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); // get feed
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  
  var rows = [Object.keys(dataAll)]; // Get headers.
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
    temp.push(dataAll[rows[0][i]]); // Get values.
  }
  rows.push(temp);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); // Put values to Spreadsheet.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
var tR = dataAll.ActualObjectName.length;    

var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i< tR; i++){
        var newJson = Object.keys(dataAll.ActualObjectName[i]).map(function (key) { 
          return [i, key, dataAll.ActualObjectName[i][key]];//change with actual object name  
          
        }); 
        for(var j = 0; j< newJson.length; j++){
          
          array.push(newJson[j]);
          
          }
          
        }
    
      sheet.getRange("A1:D49000").clearContent();//change actual range  
      var range = sheet.getRange(1,2, array.length, array[0].length);
      range.setValues(array);
```

Note: You can get the `ActualObjectName` by `console.log(dataAll)` and check for the headers object name

Comment: I inserted your code, printed an array of objects to the console, and as a result, an error occurs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: here is an array of objects that is displayed on the console                                                 { category_id: 17027490,
       title: 'Антиквариат и коллекционирование',
       children: [Object] },
     { category_id: 17027495,
       title: 'Автотовары',
       children: [Object] },
     { category_id: 17027496,
       title: 'Продукты питания',
       children: [Object] } ] }

Comment: Indicates an error in this line ---->>>>  var tR = dataAll.ActualObjectName.length;

Comment: There must be something before  `{ category_id: 17027490'`, the console is ending with `] }` whereas there is no opening array `[`

Comment: here is the beginning of the array                                                                                                              { result: 
   [ { category_id: 29,
       title: 'Печатные издания',
       children: [Object] },
     { category_id: 99999999,
       title: 'Продукт медиа',
       children: [Object] },
     { category_id: 52265716, title: 'Аптека', children: [Object] },

Comment: Try replacing `ActualObjectName` with `result`

Comment: thanks, this solution helped fix the error and split the data into columns

Comment: @Nikita great to hear that it helped you, pls don't forget to upvote the answer